# Self-intersecting torus is not a manifold

Tags: general-topology

If we define a torus as the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at distance $b$ from the circle of radius $a$ in the $xy$-plane, then tori with $b \geq a$ are not Euclidean manifolds. I think this is because no neighborhood of the intersection point is homeomorphic to a subset of $R^m$, but how can I go about proving this?

Comment: If you are talking about smooth submanifolds, you can use the fact that the speed vectors of curves passing through such a point span a three-dimensional subspace.

Comment: I just mean a topological manifold.

Comment: Well, in that case you say that you think that it is «because no neighborhood […] is homeomorphic to a subset of $R^n$» but in fact that is just the *definition*!

Answer (score 0):

Assume it is a manifold.
Its clear that if it's a manifold then it's dimension is 2.
Remove the two intersection points. Then you will be left with two connected components.

But  if you remove two points in any open set of the plane you can never get two connected components.Thus we arrive at a contradiction.